# What's the meaning of return val about the "write_packet()/seek()" callback functions in "AVIOContext" struct?

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

I'm writing a muxer DirectShow Filter using libav, I need to redirect muxer's output to filter's output pin, So I use `avio_alloc_context()` to create AVIOContext with my `write_packet` and `seek` callback functions, these 2 functions are defined below:

```
int (*write_packet)(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size)
int64_t (*seek)(void *opaque, int64_t offset, int whence)
```

I can understand the meaning of these functions' input parameters, but what's the meaning of its return? Is it means the bytes written actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int (*write_packet)(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size)`

Number of bytes written. Negative values indicate error.

`int64_t (*seek)(void *opaque, int64_t offset, int whence)`

The position of the offset, in bytes, achieved by the seek call, measured from the start of the output file. Negative values indicate error.